# Twitter API: How Do I Create a Protocol Only Callback URL?

Tags: twitter, oauth, ios13

In Twitter's [Developer Documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/apps/guides/callback-urls) we can read the following:

```
Mobile apps with app-specific protocols must use just the protocol
Example:
    You want to use example://authorize as your callback URL
    Add this to both your Twitter app dashboard and your call to oauth/request_token: example://
```

However; in the [Developer's Dashboard](https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/dashboard) I am not able to enter a protocol only URL, or any URL beginning with other than http or https.

[image: Twitter's Developer Dashboard]

My reason for wanting a protocol only URL is so that I can use in an iOS app that uses OAuthSwift to access web APIs.

Any ideas anybody?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found the answer to the original question but I do have an excellent work around. So, for anyone else who might land here:

The web app at https://oauthswift.herokuapp.com/callback 
will perform redirections. If you access that web site with the url https://oauthswift.herokuapp.com/callback/target then it will redirect to oauth-swift://oauth-callback/target.

So:

1. In the Twitter Dashboard enter https://oauthswift.herokuapp.com/callback/SomeName for your app's callback URL
2. Register oauth-swift as a URL scheme in your iOS app's URL Types
3. In your iOS app, use https://oauthswift.herokuapp.com/callback/SomeName as the callback URL for the OAuth authorization request.

Voila. Twitter will redirect to https://oauthswift.herokuapp.com/callback/SomeName which will in turn redirect to oauth-swift://oauth-callback/SomeName, allowing your iOS app to regain control of the flow.

If you find any of this confusing then this might help: http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html